# Wrong URL for using Calendar Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to add events to the basic Calendar by using Intent. I think it's working fine but when I try to read it I always got an exception. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar/`

If I'm using  this URL: `"content://com.android.calendar/calendars"` my `ReadFromCalendar()` method shows me two IDs but non of them is correct and if I add a new event the number of the IDs doesn't change. So I guess it's not the correct URL.

If I'm using this URL:`"content://com.android.calendar/" + "events"` then I got IDs from the lowest value to the highest value. When I add a new event the IDs value growing with +1 no matter what set to ID.

So the quesiton is how can I get the correct eventID-s from my calendar? Am I using the wrong URL?

Here is the what I'm using:

```
    public class CalendarUtils {

    static int numC = 0;
    private final Activity activity;

    public CalendarUtils(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void InsertAnEvent() {
        numC++;
        long event_id = numC;

        Calendar calendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        i.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        i.putExtra("beginTime", calendarEvent.getTimeInMillis());
        i.putExtra("allDay", true);
        i.putExtra("_id", event_id);
        i.putExtra("rule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        i.putExtra("endTime", calendarEvent.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
        i.putExtra("title", "Eskuvo");

        activity.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void ReadFromCalendar() {

        Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(activity));
        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = cr.query(EVENTS_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            Log.d("TAG", "ID: " + id);
            if (id == 63) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "győztél", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    public static String getCalendarUriBase(Activity activity) {
        String calendarUriBase = null;
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        Cursor managedCursor = null;

        try {
            managedCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(calendars,
                    null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
        } else {
            calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
            try {
                managedCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(calendars,
                        null, null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (managedCursor != null) {
                calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
            }
        }
        return calendarUriBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the same code in order to create an event on calendar. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9749833/2013835