# Handle Calendar's buttons Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar

I can open the default Calendar and save events. I'd like to call a method IF I click on the Save button in the calendar. I'm using this code:

CalendarUtolis.java

```
public void InsertAnEvent() {

    Calendar calendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    i.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    i.putExtra("beginTime", calendarEvent.getTimeInMillis());
    i.putExtra("allDay", true);
    i.putExtra("rule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
    i.putExtra("endTime", calendarEvent.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    i.putExtra("title", "Eskuvo");

    activity.startActivityForResult(i, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){

    if(activity.RESULT_CANCELED==resultCode){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "No events added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        getNewEventId(activity.getContentResolver(),CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,activity);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    CalendarUtils u = new CalendarUtils(this);
    u.onActivityResult(0,resultCode,data);
}
```

The problem is it doesn't matter I save or not it always shows that "No events added". Have you any idea why?

Comment: I click on the Save button to save the event into the Calendar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482514/android-calendar-get-event-id

Comment: Can you save it in any other way?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for add event to calendar.

First call this method.

```
private void saveToCalender()
{

    try {

        long eventId=0;
        try {

            TGOption finalOption = options.get(0);
            long startMili = finalOption.getTimeInterval();
            long endMili = finalOption.getToTimeInterval();

            eventId=   addEventToCalender(this.getContentResolver(),this.project.getProjectName(),"","",1,startMili *1000,endMili*1000,true,false);



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventId=-1;
        }
        finally {

            if(eventId>0) {
           youract.this.finish();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,this.getResources().getString(R.string.calender_error),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }


}
```

Add event method.

```
 /**
 * Add a new event into a native Google calendar. Add alert notification by setting <code>isRemind</code> as <code>true</code>.
 * @param cr - ContentResolver
 * @param title - Event title
 * @param addInfo - Event description
 * @param place - Event place
 * @param status -  <code>int</code> This information is sufficient for most entries: tentative (0), confirmed (1) or canceled (2):
 * @param startDate - <code>long</code> event start time in mls
 * @param isRemind - <code>boolean</code> need to remind about event before?
 * @param isMailService - <code>boolean</code>. Adding attendees to the meeting
 * @return <code>long</code> eventID
 */
public static long addEventToCalender(ContentResolver cr, String title, String addInfo, String place, int status,
                                      long startDate,long endDate, boolean isRemind, boolean isMailService) {
    String eventUriStr = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    // id, We need to choose from our mobile for primary its 1
    event.put("calendar_id", 1);
    event.put("title", title);
    event.put("description", addInfo);
    event.put("eventLocation", place);
    event.put("eventTimezone", "UTC/GMT +2:00");

    // For next 1hr

    event.put("dtstart", startDate);
    event.put("dtend", endDate);
    //If it is bithday alarm or such kind (which should remind me for whole day) 0 for false, 1 for true
    // values.put("allDay", 1);
    event.put("eventStatus", 0);
    event.put("hasAlarm", 1);
    long eventID=0;

    try {

        Uri eventUri = cr.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriStr), event);
         eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return -1;
    }



    try {
        if (isRemind) {
            String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";
            ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();
            reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
            // Default value of the system. Minutes is a integer
            reminderValues.put("minutes", 5);
            // Alert Methods: Default(0), Alert(1), Email(2), SMS(3)
            reminderValues.put("method", 1);
            cr.insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues); //Uri reminderUri =
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return eventID;
    }
    if (isMailService) {
        String attendeuesesUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/attendees";
        /********* To add multiple attendees need to insert ContentValues multiple times ***********/
        ContentValues attendeesValues = new ContentValues();
        attendeesValues.put("event_id", eventID);
        // Attendees name
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeName", "xxxxx");
        // Attendee email
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeEmail", "yyyy@gmail.com");
        // Relationship_Attendee(1), Relationship_None(0), Organizer(2), Performer(3), Speaker(4)
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeRelationship", 0);
        // None(0), Optional(1), Required(2), Resource(3)
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeType", 0);
        // None(0), Accepted(1), Decline(2), Invited(3), Tentative(4)
        attendeesValues.put("attendeeStatus", 0);
        cr.insert(Uri.parse(attendeuesesUriString), attendeesValues); //Uri attendeuesesUri =
    }

    return eventID;
}
```

Comment: It looks great but if I use this code I have to create the layout on my own?

Comment: yes, you can call this method from your own layout click.

Comment: But this is why I'd like to use Intent. Because it's a perfect event creator and all I need to do is to save the event's id and that's why I need to handle saving.